# How do I turn the following INSERT into a prepared statement so that its secure?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get my head around prepared statements.

Basically, I would do a insert like so normally:

```
$sql = '
    INSERT INTO customers 
      (customer_first, customer_last, customer_address, customer_email)
    VALUES
      (' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_first']) . ', 
      ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_last']) . ', 
      ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_address']) . ', 
      ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_email']) . '  )  
  ';
  mysql_query($sql);
```

From what I've been told however there is a more secure way to do this using Prepared Statements.

So far I think it is done like so:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (customer_first, customer_last, customer_address, customer_email) VALUES (:customer_first, :customer_last, :customer_address, :customer_email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':customer_first', $_POST['customer_first']);
$stmt->bindParam(':customer_last', $_POST['customer_last']);
$stmt->bindParam(':customer_address', $_POST['customer_address']);
$stmt->bindParam(':customer_email', $_POST['customer_email']);

$stmt->execute();
```

Is this correct? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve? If I try the above I get an error "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" - what does that mean?

I'm using the examples @ http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. It refers to a $dbh - where does it get that from? Is $dbh supposed to be referenced elsewhere - I'm assuming it is something to do with the database connection?

In addition to those questions, can I still use things like mysql_insert_id() or mysql_error() using prepared statements like above?

Comment: Aside from some application-dependant checking (enforcing a name is not empty etc.) it seems OK, as in SQL-injection safe. Keep in mind you could also forgo the `->bindParam()` calls and just call `$dbh->execute($_POST);`

Comment: +1 - It's questions like this which re-affirm my faith in developers.  Usually people are so defensive about their inline SQL concatenations.

Comment: They're equivalent to me.  FYI: PreparedStatements can't help dynamic parameters for an IN clause - has to be done as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to OOP, you could start with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for more immediately familiar functionality and syntax and support for functional programming, but it's worth reviewing the [PDO class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) if you're ready to tackle OOP.

Worth reviewing to help decide where to start: [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

> It refers to a $dbh - where does it
>   get that from? Is $dbh supposed to be
>   referenced elsewhere - I'm assuming it
>   is something to do with the database
>   connection?

$dbh = database handle (as defined in the [PDO > Connections and Connection Management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) doc)

> Can I still use things like
>   mysql_insert_id() or mysql_error()
>   using prepared statements like above?

[PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), [PDO::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: Thanks heaps for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates your problem is with the `$dbh` object -- how is it initialized?

Comment: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $user, $pass);

Comment: Is that the only other relevant code? Is it right above this line? Try doing print_r($dbh)